# Returning a method's value c# error 'keyword followed by void'

Tags: c#, excel, methods, return, buttonclick

I've created a method which selects all the cells in Excel beginning with a1 and ending when there are no more columns or rows.  When a button is clicked, I then want to initiate this so that it selects them, however I am getting an error that I can't return the value.  This is what I have:

```
    public void selectAllCells(Worksheet activeSheet)
    {
        activeSheet.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn.Select();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        return selectAllCells;
    }
```

EDIT: To make it a little more understandable.

I've got a method called selectAllCells() which will select all of the cells within a document.  When button1 is clicked (button1_Click) I want it to initiate the selectAllCells method.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to change `return selectAllCells;` to `selectAllCells();` but it's hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button click function does not have a return type, yet you are attempting to return something. I think what you are looking for is:

```
public void selectAllCells(Worksheet activeSheet)
{
    activeSheet.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn.Select();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    selectAllCells([..you need to add your active sheet here somehow..]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Theo That is effectively what I want to do.  When the button is pressed I want it to select all the rows and columns, I just had no idea how to properly go about it. C# is still very new to me.

Comment: The above code does what you want, so what is the problem? If it is related to passing the worksheet into the function then you will need to provide more context. Where is the button? How are you opening and manipulating the workbook ... theres not a lot to work with here.

Comment: Oh there is no problem :)

Comment: Ahh :) Cool! Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Methods with the void keyword aren't expecting anything to be returned, yet you're attempting to return something.

If you're just trying to select the columns, you don't need the return keyword on the method call.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    selectAllCells(--workbookgoeshere--);
}
```